# Python Ошибка при чтении файла

Tags: python

Если в файле строки такого типа :

first

second

то всё норм,а если начинаются с

> "@" вот такие например @David,@masha,@sergey

То появляется Ошибка

> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 2291:character maps to undefined>

Я понимаю что ошибка с кодировкой,но не пойму на что исправить,и в каких случаях(при использовании каких знаков) появляется такая ошибка.

Код

```
ra = open("user_name", "r")
for i in ra:
  print(i)
```

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: В какой момент возникает ошибка - при открытии файла или при выводе на экран?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать кодировку при открытии файла:

```
ra = open("user_name", "r", encoding="utf8")
```